# Configuring SFTP in Pycharm

Tags: ssh, sftp, remote-access

I'm trying to setup Pycharm such that my local changes are automatically deployed to a remote server.

I can `ssh remoteserver` and also `sftp remoteserver` from the terminal so access is not an issue. But if I try to setup deployment in Pycharm using SFTP, it can't establish the connection.

My best guess is that it's an authentication issue. When running the ssh or sftp commands separately, I've never needed to enter a username or password, so I suppose the auth is happening via Private Key. But the problem is that I'm not sure where the Private Key actually is (I'm in an unfamiliar dev environment).

So either

1. How do I know which Private Key I'm using when running `ssh` or `sftp`?
2. Any other way to resolve the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As to (1), the [SSH man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201) says (under the `-i` option) "The default is `~/.ssh/identity` for protocol version 1, and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_dsa` for protocol version 2.  Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file."

The configuration file is `~/.ssh/config`, and the key file for a particular host is specified with `IdentityFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run ssh with -vvv parameter. The location of the private key file will be printed out (if key authentication is used).